# Could not connect to vsftp on fedora from filezilla

Tags: fedora, vsftpd

I am very confused as to why I cannot connect to my fedora server from my desktop through filezilla.

I think I have added the service to the firewall (though when I use firewall-cmd --list-services it does not show...) and the server is started, I can telnet into it from the 192 IP locally but from my desktop it just says

```
Status: Connecting to 192.168.1.113:21...
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

is my configuration incorrect?

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release
Fedora release 21 (Twenty One)

[root@localhost /]# netstat -ntulp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:445             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      981/smbd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:139             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      981/smbd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      838/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      1452/httpd
tcp6       0      0 :::445                  :::*                    LISTEN      981/smbd
tcp6       0      0 :::9090                 :::*                    LISTEN      1/systemd
tcp6       0      0 :::139                  :::*                    LISTEN      981/smbd
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1452/httpd
tcp6       0      0 :::21                   :::*                    LISTEN      1559/vsftpd
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      838/sshd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           958/dhclient
udp        0      0 192.168.1.255:137       0.0.0.0:*                           840/nmbd
udp        0      0 192.168.1.113:137       0.0.0.0:*                           840/nmbd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:137             0.0.0.0:*                           840/nmbd
udp        0      0 192.168.1.255:138       0.0.0.0:*                           840/nmbd
udp        0      0 192.168.1.113:138       0.0.0.0:*                           840/nmbd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:138             0.0.0.0:*                           840/nmbd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:11320           0.0.0.0:*                           958/dhclient
udp6       0      0 :::18941                :::*                                958/dhclient
```

vsftpd.conf

```
# Example config file /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf
#
# The default compiled in settings are fairly paranoid. This sample file
# loosens things up a bit, to make the ftp daemon more usable.
# Please see vsftpd.conf.5 for all compiled in defaults.
#
# READ THIS: This example file is NOT an exhaustive list of vsftpd options.
# Please read the vsftpd.conf.5 manual page to get a full idea of vsftpd's
# capabilities.
#
# Allow anonymous FTP? (Beware - allowed by default if you comment this out).
anonymous_enable=YES
#
# Uncomment this to allow local users to log in.
# When SELinux is enforcing check for SE bool ftp_home_dir
local_enable=YES
#
# Uncomment this to enable any form of FTP write command.
write_enable=YES
#
# Default umask for local users is 077. You may wish to change this to 022,
# if your users expect that (022 is used by most other ftpd's)
local_umask=022
#
# Uncomment this to allow the anonymous FTP user to upload files. This only
# has an effect if the above global write enable is activated. Also, you will
# obviously need to create a directory writable by the FTP user.
# When SELinux is enforcing check for SE bool allow_ftpd_anon_write, allow_ftpd_full_access
#anon_upload_enable=YES
#
# Uncomment this if you want the anonymous FTP user to be able to create
# new directories.
#anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
#
# Activate directory messages - messages given to remote users when they
# go into a certain directory.
dirmessage_enable=YES
#
# Activate logging of uploads/downloads.
xferlog_enable=YES
#
# Make sure PORT transfer connections originate from port 20 (ftp-data).
connect_from_port_20=YES
#
# If you want, you can arrange for uploaded anonymous files to be owned by
# a different user. Note! Using "root" for uploaded files is not
# recommended!
#chown_uploads=YES
#chown_username=whoever
#
# You may override where the log file goes if you like. The default is shown
# below.
#xferlog_file=/var/log/xferlog
#
# If you want, you can have your log file in standard ftpd xferlog format.
# Note that the default log file location is /var/log/xferlog in this case.
xferlog_std_format=YES
#log_ftp_protocol=YES
#
# You may change the default value for timing out an idle session.
#idle_session_timeout=600
#
# You may change the default value for timing out a data connection.
#data_connection_timeout=120
#
# It is recommended that you define on your system a unique user which the
# ftp server can use as a totally isolated and unprivileged user.
#nopriv_user=ftpsecure
#
# Enable this and the server will recognise asynchronous ABOR requests. Not
# recommended for security (the code is non-trivial). Not enabling it,
# however, may confuse older FTP clients.
#async_abor_enable=YES
#
# By default the server will pretend to allow ASCII mode but in fact ignore
# the request. Turn on the below options to have the server actually do ASCII
# mangling on files when in ASCII mode.
# Beware that on some FTP servers, ASCII support allows a denial of service
# attack (DoS) via the command "SIZE /big/file" in ASCII mode. vsftpd
# predicted this attack and has always been safe, reporting the size of the
# raw file.
# ASCII mangling is a horrible feature of the protocol.
#ascii_upload_enable=YES
#ascii_download_enable=YES
#
# You may fully customise the login banner string:
#ftpd_banner=Welcome to blah FTP service.
#
# You may specify a file of disallowed anonymous e-mail addresses. Apparently
# useful for combatting certain DoS attacks.
#deny_email_enable=YES
# (default follows)
#banned_email_file=/etc/vsftpd/banned_emails
#
# You may specify an explicit list of local users to chroot() to their home
# directory. If chroot_local_user is YES, then this list becomes a list of
# users to NOT chroot().
# (Warning! chroot'ing can be very dangerous. If using chroot, make sure that
# the user does not have write access to the top level directory within the
# chroot)
#chroot_local_user=YES
#chroot_list_enable=YES
# (default follows)
#chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd/chroot_list
#
# You may activate the "-R" option to the builtin ls. This is disabled by
# default to avoid remote users being able to cause excessive I/O on large
# sites. However, some broken FTP clients such as "ncftp" and "mirror" assume
# the presence of the "-R" option, so there is a strong case for enabling it.
#ls_recurse_enable=YES
#
# When "listen" directive is enabled, vsftpd runs in standalone mode and
# listens on IPv4 sockets. This directive cannot be used in conjunction
# with the listen_ipv6 directive.
listen=NO
#
# This directive enables listening on IPv6 sockets. By default, listening
# on the IPv6 "any" address (::) will accept connections from both IPv6
# and IPv4 clients. It is not necessary to listen on *both* IPv4 and IPv6
# sockets. If you want that (perhaps because you want to listen on specific
# addresses) then you must run two copies of vsftpd with two configuration
# files.
# Make sure, that one of the listen options is commented !!
listen_ipv6=YES
pam_service_name=vsftpd
userlist_enable=YES
tcp_wrappers=YES
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was that the ftp service was not actually permanently added to the firewall, simply using the following line worked

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=ftp
```

and following that with

```
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Answer (score 0):

Your vsftpd server listening over IPv6 only and you're trying to connect using IPv4. That's why it's not connecting. Read the configuration file. It's mentioned.

Look the "netstat -tunlep" output. The vsftpd demon is bound to :::21 port only and not to IPv4.

Edit this two line as follows in your configuration

```
listen=YES
listen_ipv6=NO
```

Restart your vsftpd server. Hope filezilla will successfully connect. If you want to run vsftpd over both IPv4 and IPv6 run two copy of the daemon.